# Cannot find values inside of an array?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to do stuff with moderation and I can't use an array for a wordlist because it isn't letting me check if a message includes any value in the array. How can I see if a value in one array (words) matches with any value in another array (lang.blacklisted)? Here is my code snippet:

```
let words = message.content.split(' ');
    if (words.includes(lang.blacklisted.values())) {
        message.channel.send('word')
    }
```

Comment: What type is `lang.blacklisted`? Is it an object?

Comment: Includes should be a "certain" value, not a set or an array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if any word is part of your blacklist (and I assume your blacklist is a set), you could do

```
let words = message.content.split(' ').map( w => w.toUpperCase() );
if (words.some( word => lang.blacklisted.has( word ) ) ) {
  message.channel.send('word');
}
```

if you want to find the exact word that would trigger it

```
let words = message.content.split(' ').map( w => w.toUpperCase() );
let blacklisted = words.find( word => lang.blacklisted.has( word ) );
if (blacklisted) {
  message.channel.send( blacklisted );
}
```

if it could be a series of words

```
let words = message.content.split(' ').map( w => w.toUpperCase() );
let blacklisted = words.filter( word => lang.blacklisted.has( word ) );
if (blacklisted.length) {
  // this will send all words found in lang.blacklisted 
  message.channel.send( blacklisted );
}
```

The lines above assume:

- `lang.blacklisted` is a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- `lang.blacklisted` values are uppercased